# SSIS Execute Process Task Hanging when Standard Error Variable Provided

Tags: python, ssis

I am using SSIS's Execute Process Task to execute a compiled python script.

The script executes as expected and completes as expected with either success or failure.

However, when I configure a variable to catch Standard Error or Standard Output, the application hangs. The command prompt flashes up and down indicating that the execution has completed but then the SSIS task itself never completes.

To reiterate, when I don't configure the variable, there is no issue and the task finishes as expected. I have also debugged the execution of the script independently and I can verify that:

- Status code is 0 when success.
- Standard error contains text.

Any ideas what is causing the task to hang?

Comment: Can you try by changing the "Delay validation" of Execute Process task to TRUE?

Comment: Hi @Pinwar13. It's not failing at compilation time but at runtime. Delay Validation shouldn't impact this but in any case, it is set to True anyway.

Comment: Variables are of string? Have you tried one variable at a time for debugging?

Comment: I used breakpoints and watch windows to debug the variables yes but the problem was the task was not completed. This is actually now solved; I was writing to a parent package variable (i.e. by creating the variable in the child package, configuring the task, setting delay validation to true and then deleting the variable) - it appears when I do this, it takes SSIS a long time to write to it! If i use a child package variable, it completes straight away but it takes 1-2 minutes for the parent package variable to be written to. At least it's completing.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually now solved - or rather, never actually broken; I was writing to a parent package variable (i.e. by creating the variable in the child package, configuring the task, setting delay validation to true and then deleting the variable) - it appears when I do this, it takes SSIS a long time to write to it! If i use a child package variable, it completes straight away but it takes 1-2 minutes for the parent package variable to be written to.

At least it's completing.